# Which object should I synchronize on?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

A java application has 3 objects, among others. A Student object that holds all needed info about a student. A List, ArrayList, that holds the Student objects. And a RandomAccessFile that reads and writes the student info to a file.

If multiple threads will be accessing the list, adding, removing and modifying the Student objects, at the same time writing to the disk, which object should I synchronize on in the add, remove, modify and writing to disk? Student, ArrayList, or RandomAccessFile? And is there a performance gain/loss if I choose one over the other?

In a book I'm reading the synchronization is done on the Student object but I found an online source code that the synchronization is done on the RandomAccessFile?

I would very much appreciate your clarification

Comment: What do __you__ think and why?

Comment: Is this a standard `ArrayList`, or is it a [`Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) / [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise it makes no difference what object you synchronize on (just make sure it is always the *same* instance, in all cases).  However...

You would be better off providing a single instance of a class (say StudentData) that hides the list and values (Students) and provides the basic operations you need: add(Student), get(String studentId)?, remove(String studentId)?, etc, etc.  (Aside: if your Student objects *have* ids, you might be better putting them in a map, not a list.)

All of these methods would be declared synchronized (and would therefore synchronize on the StudentData instance) so each would complete atomically, before any subsequent change by another thread to the overall StudentData structure.

Two caveats:

- If your Student objects are mutable (i.e. have getters/setters) you will need return a copy of the Student instance when returning from get() and copy the data from the passed in Student value to the one in the list (or map) in the StudentData on update()/add().  Otherwise, the state of the Student could be modified after the StudentData method finishes with it, via the reference to it (allowing updates outside of the synchronized code).
- You shouldn't do I/O in synchronized code.  If you do, something that blocks I/O will prevent the synchronization lock from completing, and everything will stop, until I/O unblocks.   (In fact, you should always limit the work done in synchronized code to the bare minimum needed.)  One approach, if your data set is not too large, would be to synchronously take a copy of the whole data set then, outside of the synchronized code, write this all to disk.
- But, if you are going to be using a RandomAccessFile to manage some sort of on-disk record structure (rather than, say, a saved text representation of the data - e.g. XML, JSON), why not just use a RDBMS instead?

Comment: +1 You make some good points. wrt RandomAccessFile , it may be a requirement for a class exercise that he roll his own, but if it's for work, then yes, it'd be simpler to use an existing tool.

Comment: [[ You shouldn't do I/O in synchronized code. ]] A question - If there is only one file where the list of students is written to, then where should I/O be done, if not in synchronized code.

Comment: @SatishMotwani - If it's a classroom exercise, you may want to just not worry about it. If it's for a real project, using a separate command-processing thread solves this.

Comment: Thanks @DonBranson. Not a real project. This is for my learning. [[ using a separate command-processing thread solves this ]] You mean to say that I can have another Timer and TimerTask that keeps writing the studentList to the RandomAccessFile at regular intervals. It will also need to synchronize on the common studentList in memory and perform write to file in the synchronized block. This is to prevent changes to studentList when the thread is writing to file.

Comment: @SatishMotwani - No, not Timers. I was thinking of something like http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-threadpoolexecutor-to-parallelize.html. Once that thread is running, your main thread or other threads can add items to that queue, and the thread executor will execute them in the order of their arrival.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the first point of the Two caveats, If your Student objects are mutable? I don't fully understand this point.

Comment: aaah okay. Thanks @DonBranson. Is this right - We create a SingleThreadExecutor. When we modify the common resource (instance of studentList in memory), we submit a new Runnable which updates the file on disk. So no need to synchronize on list for IO here, the Runnables will execute sequentially. For operations that modify list, we synchronize the addStudent( ), removeStudent () methods.

Comment: @SatishMotwani I was thinking that you'd update the common resource in a Runnable, too. Not the same one, necessarily, but it could be.

Comment: @DonBranson, that sounds good too. what I had in mind is - Runnable only writes to files. pass the list to the Runnable. submit the Runnable to SingleThreadExecutor. That solves the problem of not performing IO in synchronized block.  I saw your reply, looks good. thanks for your time.

Comment: @SatishMotwani You're welcome. However, if you're updating the list in a separate thread, you still have to code the synchronization, or the writer thread can be writing a list that's in an unknown state. And if you do the sync, then your single writing thread will block the others while it writes. You'd have to do all access in the single thread, or make deep copies for the writer. So, more complexity. Very likely overkill for a classroom exercise.

Comment: @DonBranson. aah i get it. so I will have to synchronize at both places - 1. in the Runnables submitted to the SingleThreadExecutor and 2. update studentList methods. We do not want a situation where a thread is adding/removing a student to the list while the Runnable in SingleThreadExecutor is writing the list to file. I agree, overkill for a classroom exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Single Responsibility Principle as applied to these member variables, why try to use any of them to serve two purposes: both to store the data and for locking? I'd create a separate member variable just for the lock:

```
class Student {
    private String name;

    Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
private final Object lock = new Object();

...

public void updateList(){
    Student newGuy = new Student("Joe");
    synchronized (lock){
        students.add(newGuy);
    }
}
```

Having said that, Paul makes a good point about not doing IO within the synchronized block. An alternative to a lock which would move the IO out of the synchronized block, though it's more complex, is to use a Command pattern in combination with a single thread that executes commands from a queue. One command could add a student to the list, a subsequent command could write the list to a file. You can have as many threads as you like throwing new commands onto the queue, and they'll all be executed in the order they arrive. Again, apply SRP here. Each command should do one thing only.

Edit:

So while this is probably more than you want to bite off for class, this elaborates on the command-queue idea.

[image]

Each command is a runnable where the run() method do what you want - adds a student, writes to disk, whatever. Once you start the executor thread, it just sits there waiting for new commands to show up in the queue. If there are no commands, it blocks, but the other threads can continue executing. If there are commands, it runs in parallel with the other threads.

Comment: If I follow your approach, the separate member variable should be declared in the Student class, where the data is modified. Does it make any sense to code a class as the lock? Make it a singleton class. And will that have any advantage or simply the member variable is enough.

Comment: "Does it make any sense to code a class as the lock?" If you mean create a new class to act as a lock, no. Just use Object. And I would not put the lock in Student, I'd put in in the class that has the list of Student objects, as shown above.

Comment: Will this be all the synchronization required? Or do I have to also synchronize the methods that modify variables of the Student class?

Comment: You would want to synchronize any blocks that modify the list. Is Student mutable? Does it need to be? It'd be better if it's immutable.

Comment: The Student is mutable and I'd prefer if it remains. Now, if I make it immutable, is all required is to synchronize any blocks that accesses the list and if the Student attributes need to be modified, create a new object an update the reference. If the Student class remain mutable, what would be required?

Comment: If you have multiple threads that can modify the same student, that complicates things. If Student's mutable, you probably would need a separate lock on each instance of Student in addition the the lock on the list. If they're immutable, you would have to create a new Student whenever a change to a Student is needed, the new one replacing the old, but you'd only need the one lock on the list.